# Consolidating columns of data in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerquery

I am looking for assistance with managing excel sheets that contain a bunch of data for members of a club. the way the data is generated is each column is a membership they have like below:

[image]

I have been managing manually but I want to see if its possible for a query to help to consolidate the columns in to this

[image]

I have tried using power query, and unpivoting columns but I just can't quite get the correct process.

for simplicity's sake I have just used 3 columns for each of the desc start and end, however in the documents I use there are more if that information is needed.

note the images are just done on google doc as I'm away from my computer just now

I have tried to use power queries in excel in the data tab, and selecting all the columns i want changed however can't quite get the correct product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in powerquery. It unpivots, splits off the numerical part, then repivots

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {"Member ID"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
#"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", "Attribute", Splitter.SplitTextByEachDelimiter({" "}, QuoteStyle.Csv, true), {"Activity", "Count"}),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Split Column by Delimiter", List.Distinct(#"Split Column by Delimiter"[Activity]), "Activity", "Value"),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Pivoted Column",{{"sub start", type date}, {"sub end", type date}})
in  #"Changed Type"
```

[image]

Comment: Hey There, Thank you for your help! Putting this in to the Advanced editor worked for me.